# ERROR : Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I try to create a module Users I am inspire from the Blog Exemple of zend 2.4, I build a factory to instantiate my controller UsersController, but i get this error:

```
An exception was raised while creating "Users\Controller\Users"; no instance returned
```

Actually the problem arise when I bring the service into the controler

```
class UsersController extends AbstractActionController {

    protected $userService;

    public function __construct(UserServiceInterface $userService){
        $this->userService = $userService ;
    }
}
```

Then I defined UserServiceInterface and create an instance of the 'Users\Controller\UserController' and change the configuration:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
         'Users\Controller\Users' => 'Users\Factory\UserControllerFactory'
     )
),
```

And Writing a Factory Class UserControllerFactory :

```
class UserControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator){
        $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $userService= $realServiceLocator->get('Users\Service\UserServiceInterface');

        return new UsersController($userService);
    }
}
```

The UserService has a dependency :

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Users\Service\UserServiceInterface' => 'Users\Factory\UserServiceFactory',
        'Users\Mapper\PostMapperInterface'   => 'Users\Factory\ZendDbSqlMapperFactory',
     )
),
```

I get also

```
Previous exceptions:
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException
File:
D:\wamp\www\AppZend2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php:1101
Message:
While attempting to create usersserviceuserserviceinterface(alias: Users\Service\UserServiceInterface) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.
```

this is my UserServiceFactory :

```
use Users\Service\UserService;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class UserServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new UserService(
            $serviceLocator->get('Users\Mapper\PostMapperInterface')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: have you got a namespace declaration in the UserServiceFactory?
namespace Users\Factory; - seems not to be able to find the factory

Comment: @Andrew thnak you the namespace  was the problem.